# click event handler for an id that is non responsive. (or at-least I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, bootstrap-4

I have built out a pop-up button module using Bootstrap with the intent in adding it to each of my product pages. The roadblock Issue I am having is listed below.

*This is my first post here so If there is anything posted that would not be necessary or how I format the issue should be different please let me know.

The issue is I have set a drop down  to allow the site's users to select the topic of their email information request. The other option presented me with the question, should I remove the drop down and provide a text filed for the user to fill out to best suit their needs for the evolution.

I am unable to figure a response in the console (at my tech ability) so I know how to assign it to disappear and allow the other field to appear when the "other" option is selected. I have two variants attached and was hoping to get one of them to work but have been unsuccessful. Please advise.

Thank you!
J

```js
//What I expected to work and did not. 

/* First attempt code start  */
//             $(document).ready(function(){
//         console.log("Do Something rad today...");
//         $('#mce-other-subject').hide();
//         });

//         $('#tenth-choice').on("click", function () {

//          $('#mce-MMERGE3').hide();
//          $('#mce-other-subject').show();

//         });


/* First attempt code end  */



/* Second attempt code start  */

//         var newDiv = document.getElementById('tenth-choice');
//         newDiv.addEventListener("click", listener, false);

//         function listener() {
//           document.getElementById('tenth-choice').innerHTML = "other";
//         $('#mce-MMERGE3').hide();
//         $('#mce-other-subject').show();
//         }

//         /* Second attempt code end  */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Working primary content for button click  -  Module pop out -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- additional meta tags -->
  <meta author=" Jxxxx Sxxxx ">
  <meta copyright="© 2019 | Jxxxx Sxxxx ">
  <meta user="RxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxx.com">
  <meta keywords="bootstrap, html, jquery, module, button, contact, form, javascript">

  <!-- Jquery | Javascript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>

</head>

<body>


  <!--------------- primary button ---------------------------------->

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" id="ques-btn" style=" margin-left: 40%; margin-top:10%;">
                Have Questions
              </button>

  <!--------------- Modal Begin ----------------------->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .003);">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Contact Our Tech Department</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
          <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <style type="text/css">
            #mc_embed_signup {
              background-color: "rgba(255,255,255, .003)";
              clear: left;
              font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
          </style>
          <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="https://thedomain.com/things/morethings/onelastthing" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
              <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <h2>Have questions? We are here to help</h2>
                <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-EMAIL">&nbsp;<span class="asterisk"></span>
</label>
                  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder=" * Your@email.com * ">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-FNAME">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-LNAME">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>

                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-Link">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="LINK" class="" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="https://linkGoesHere.com">
                </div>


                <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE4">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="number" name="MMERGE4" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE4" placeholder="5 5 5  -  5 5 5  -  5 5 5 5">
                </div>







                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE3">&nbsp;</label>
                  <select name="MMERGE3" class="" id="mce-MMERGE3">
                    <option value="">Email Subject</option>
                    <option value="First Choice">Schedule a Bike Fit</option>
                    <option value="Second Choice">Schedule Bike Service</option>
                    <option value="Third Choice">Order Question</option>
                    <option value="fourth Choice">Overseas shipping</option>
                    <option value="fifth Choice">I want to do a custom build</option>
                    <option value="Sixth Choice">I dont see it on your site, Can you get it for me?</option>
                    <option value="Seventh Choice">Request a call back</option>
                    <option value="Eigth Choice">Upcoming Rides</option>
                    <option value="Nineth Choice">Waranty</option>
                    <option value="Tenth Choice" id="tenth-choice">Other</option>

                  </select>

                  <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-other-subject">&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="other-subject" class="" id="mce-other-subject" placeholder="RE: ( alt: Custom subject )">
                  </div>


                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE5">  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE5" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE5" placeholder=" * Your quesitons go here . . . * ">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                  <strong>Format  </strong>
                  <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="html" name="EMAILTYPE" id="mce-EMAILTYPE-0"><label for="mce-EMAILTYPE-0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;html</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="text" name="EMAILTYPE" id="mce-EMAILTYPE-1"><label for="mce-EMAILTYPE-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text</label></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0e27360bc21d21bdeb3dc8509_e155794398" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
          <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function($) {
              window.fnames = new Array();
              window.ftypes = new Array();
              fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
              ftypes[0] = 'email';
              fnames[1] = 'FNAME';
              ftypes[1] = 'text';
              fnames[2] = 'LNAME';
              ftypes[2] = 'text';
              fnames[4] = 'MMERGE4';
              ftypes[4] = 'number';
              fnames[3] = 'MMERGE3';
              ftypes[3] = 'dropdown';
              fnames[5] = 'MMERGE5';
              ftypes[5] = 'text';
            }(jQuery));
            var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
          </script>


          <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[link to an image of console and client-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kopsJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you need to toggle the custom subject input field group:

```js
$(function () {
  var subjectInputGroup = $('#mce-other-subject').closest('.mc-field-group');
  subjectInputGroup.hide()
  $('#mce-MMERGE3').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('option:selected', this).attr('id') == 'tenth-choice') {
      subjectInputGroup.show()
    }
    else {
      subjectInputGroup.hide()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Working primary content for button click  -  Module pop out -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- additional meta tags -->
  <meta author=" Jxxxx Sxxxx ">
  <meta copyright="© 2019 | Jxxxx Sxxxx ">
  <meta user="RxxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxx.com">
  <meta keywords="bootstrap, html, jquery, module, button, contact, form, javascript">

  <!-- Jquery | Javascript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>

</head>

<body>


  <!--------------- primary button ---------------------------------->

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" id="ques-btn" style=" margin-left: 40%; margin-top:10%;">
                Have Questions
              </button>

  <!--------------- Modal Begin ----------------------->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .003);">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Contact Our Tech Department</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
          <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <style type="text/css">
            #mc_embed_signup {
              background-color: "rgba(255,255,255, .003)";
              clear: left;
              font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
          </style>
          <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="https://thedomain.com/things/morethings/onelastthing" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
              <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <h2>Have questions? We are here to help</h2>
                <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-EMAIL">&nbsp;<span class="asterisk"></span>
</label>
                  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder=" * Your@email.com * ">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-FNAME">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-LNAME">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>

                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-Link">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="LINK" class="" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="https://linkGoesHere.com">
                </div>


                <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE4">&nbsp;</label>
                  <input type="number" name="MMERGE4" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE4" placeholder="5 5 5  -  5 5 5  -  5 5 5 5">
                </div>







                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE3">&nbsp;</label>
                  <select name="MMERGE3" class="" id="mce-MMERGE3">
                    <option value="">Email Subject</option>
                    <option value="First Choice">Schedule a Bike Fit</option>
                    <option value="Second Choice">Schedule Bike Service</option>
                    <option value="Third Choice">Order Question</option>
                    <option value="fourth Choice">Overseas shipping</option>
                    <option value="fifth Choice">I want to do a custom build</option>
                    <option value="Sixth Choice">I dont see it on your site, Can you get it for me?</option>
                    <option value="Seventh Choice">Request a call back</option>
                    <option value="Eigth Choice">Upcoming Rides</option>
                    <option value="Nineth Choice">Waranty</option>
                    <option value="Tenth Choice" id="tenth-choice">Other</option>

                  </select>

                  <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-other-subject">&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="other-subject" class="" id="mce-other-subject" placeholder="RE: ( alt: Custom subject )">
                  </div>


                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-MMERGE5">  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE5" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE5" placeholder=" * Your quesitons go here . . . * ">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                  <strong>Format  </strong>
                  <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="html" name="EMAILTYPE" id="mce-EMAILTYPE-0"><label for="mce-EMAILTYPE-0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;html</label></li>
                    <li><input type="radio" value="text" name="EMAILTYPE" id="mce-EMAILTYPE-1"><label for="mce-EMAILTYPE-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text</label></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0e27360bc21d21bdeb3dc8509_e155794398" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
          <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function($) {
              window.fnames = new Array();
              window.ftypes = new Array();
              fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
              ftypes[0] = 'email';
              fnames[1] = 'FNAME';
              ftypes[1] = 'text';
              fnames[2] = 'LNAME';
              ftypes[2] = 'text';
              fnames[4] = 'MMERGE4';
              ftypes[4] = 'number';
              fnames[3] = 'MMERGE3';
              ftypes[3] = 'dropdown';
              fnames[5] = 'MMERGE5';
              ftypes[5] = 'text';
            }(jQuery));
            var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
          </script>


          <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's an [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) shorthand alternative:

```
const subjectInputGroup = $('#mce-other-subject').closest('.mc-field-group').hide();
$('#mce-MMERGE3').on('change', e => subjectInputGroup[
  $('option:selected', e.target).attr('id') == 'tenth-choice' ? 'show' : 'hide'
]());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to listen the click on the option 10 of your list. What you need to do is listen to the onChange event of the select tag and compare the value with the option you want to condition the visibility of the input, in your case "Tenth Choice".

If the comparison is true you will be able to change the visibility as you wish. let's have a look to this example:

```js
$('#mce-MMERGE3').on("change", function (e) {
  if (e.target.value == "Tenth Choice") {
    $('#mce-MMERGE3').hide();
    $('#mce-other-subject').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.mce-other-subject {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mc-field-group">
  <label for="mce-MMERGE3">&nbsp;</label>
  <select name="MMERGE3" class="" id="mce-MMERGE3">
    <option value="">Email Subject</option>
    <option value="First Choice">Schedule a Bike Fit</option>
    <option value="Second Choice">Schedule Bike Service</option>
    <option value="Third Choice">Order Question</option>
    <option value="fourth Choice">Overseas shipping</option>
    <option value="fifth Choice">I want to do a custom build</option>
    <option value="Sixth Choice">I dont see it on your site, Can you get it for me?</option>
    <option value="Seventh Choice">Request a call back</option>
    <option value="Eigth Choice">Upcoming Rides</option>
    <option value="Nineth Choice">Waranty</option>
    <option value="Tenth Choice">Other</option>
  </select>

  <div class="mc-field-group mce-other-subject" id="mce-other-subject">
    <label for="mce-other-subject">&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="other-subject" class="" placeholder="RE: ( alt: Custom subject )">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice to hear that! :)